# Adding padding for text

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the following example the heading text is on several lines. Is it somehow possible to add the **left and right padding** on each line (without wrapping each word in a different element, of course)?

If not possible with CSS only, can it be done with jQuery?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
<h1>Donec commodo sapien lectus, nec gravida magna</h1> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    width: 100px;
}

h1{
    display:inline;
    background:green;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/289oo48b/

[image]

Comment: Without wrapping, CSS only, nope. *can it be done with jQuery* - absolutely. By wrapping each word in a `<span>` :)

Comment: Can you make an image with what you are trying to achieve? Also, why isn't styling parents allowed? Is it a code structure you can't touch? Can you use javascript if needed to add a parent on the fly?

Comment: Why using header element (H1)?

Comment: Just so we're clear - not this http://jsfiddle.net/289oo48b/4/ - right? You want the effect of lines?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I've a fixed width parent div which has inline text as you see above. I only want to add left and right padding behind each word. I guess that can't be done :(

Comment: As per RGraham comment, this may help you. http://jsfiddle.net/289oo48b/10/

Comment: A rudimentary example with jQuery which wraps spans - http://jsfiddle.net/a2fnq7xr/

Comment: @RGraham Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I'd accept if you'd have posted it as answer.

Comment: @user1355300 It doesn't really answer the question though. Just an example of how it could be done without the *without wrapping each word in a different element, of course* restriction.

Comment: So what is the goal? One word per line? or can words be on the same line?

Comment: yes, it doesn't but I quickly learned that without this it can be achieved. Also I wouldn't want to wrap every single word in a span, instead each line (which can be have multiple words, depending on the container width), but again, that's the closest answer I could get.

Comment: @Kobi goal is to get the output as RGraham, but a line can have multiple words depending on the parent container width.

Comment: @user1355300 - Then you should edit the question. Show an image of the **expected output**, not the HTML we can already see. Also, not this: http://jsfiddle.net/289oo48b/15/

Comment: It can be achieved, by modding @RGraham's solution to check for each span if the next word fits in, using the span's innerWidth property. If not, just leave the current content and move to next span.

Comment: I must say I prefer the one on the left, it reminds me of geocities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding one container (`span` for example) element for the content of the `h1`:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>
        <span>Donec commodo sapien lectus, nec gravida magna</span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

**And using following CSS:**

```
.wrap {
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    padding: 2px 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid green;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

h1 {
    display:inline;
    background:green;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 4px 0;
    margin: 0;
}

span {
    position: relative;
    left: -10px; 
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anini/rwLenu6w/

Answer (score 2):

```
.wrap{
    width: 100px;
}

h1{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: green;
    word-spacing: 100px;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a56kap9L/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean line-height like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/qayuxsft/

```
line-height: 2em;
```

or

```
line-height: 200%;
```

change `display: inline` to `display: block` to fill in the spaces with green.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant the padding on the left and right of each line so that there's some space between the background and the text.